# How to display special character in json using php

Tags: php, json

I am creating web service for android which in php.

In database, there are some rows where it contains html and css define.

While fetching data from database json shows null data.

Any Help will be helpful

Example

Vivenda dos Palhaços this shows me result "null"

My code:

```
 <?php

 error_reporting(~E_ALL);
 $format = $_REQUEST['format'];

 if(!isset($format))
 $format = "json";

 if($format == 'json') {

 header('Content-Type: application/json');

  } else if ($format == 'xml') {
  ob_clean();
  header('Content-Type: text/xml; charset=ISO-8859-1');
  echo "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1'?>";
  }

  //open database connection
  include 'config.php';
  include 'open_db_connection.php';
  include 'util.php';

  mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
  mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
  mysql_query("SET COLLATION_CONNECTION = 'utf8_unicode_ci'");

  $region = $_REQUEST['region'];
  $method = $_REQUEST['method'];


  if($method == 'GET') {


    if($region == 'Central') 

    {
                $q=$_REQUEST['q'];

                $famille_id = $_REQUEST['famille_id'];
                //print $famille_id; exit;
                $sql_fn = "SELECT * FROM region WHERE id='4'"; //Central Goa
                $result2 = mysql_query($sql_fn) or die(mysql_error());      
                $row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2);

           $sql = "select id,titre,famille_id from categorie where famille_id     =".$famille_id;
                $result     = mysql_query($sql, $db) or die(mysql_error());
                $j=0;
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 

                {

          $sql="SELECT *  FROM etablissement where categories LIKE '%".$row['id']."%' AND familles LIKE '%".$row['famille_id']."%' AND region_id LIKE '%".$row2['id']."%'";

                    $result1    = mysql_query($sql,$db) or die(mysql_error());
                    $i=0;
            while($row3 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1))
            {   

                        $arraycont[$i]['main_category_name'] = 'PARTY';
                        $arraycont[$i]['categories_name'] = $row['titre'];
                        $arraycont[$i]['categories'] = $row['id'];
                        $arraycont[$i]['sstitre'] = $row3['sstitre'];
                        $arraycont[$i]['adresse'] = $row3['adresse'];
                $arraycont[$i]['lieu'] = $row3['lieu']." / ".$row2['nom']." | ".$row['titre'];
                        $arraycont[$i]['nom'] = $row3['nom'];
                        $arraycont[$i]['txtintro'] = $row3['txtintro'];
                        $arraycont[$i]['image'] = $imagepath.$row3['id']."/01.jpg";
                        $arraycont[$i]['latitude'] = $row3['latitude'];
                        $arraycont[$i]['longitude'] = $row3['longitude'];
                        $arraycont[$i]['txtcontact'] = $row3['txtcontact'];
                        $arraycont[$i]['tel'] = $row3['tel'];

                        $i++;
                    }


        $finalarray[$j]["titre"] = $row['titre'];
      $finalarray[$j]["id"] = $row['id'];
        $finalarray[$j]["categories"] = $arraycont;
      $j++;
    }


        echo json_encode($finalarray);  // final output in JSON

   }    



   include 'close_db_connection.php';


   ?>
```

Comment: Have you tested your mysql Query? What are you getting as result when you var_dump $finalarray?

Comment: Everything is working fine only problem is the data is stored in html along with css. So when string contains some unknown characters such as Palhaços it shows me null data.
if i manually change it  Palhacos it shows immediately.

Comment: You are confusing XML with JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all You must need to set the database table collation to `UTF-8 general ci`.
then before fetch the data by select query you need to insert these char set lines.

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'UTF8'");
request_result = executre your select query.
```

Comment: After query result put this line. mysql_set_charset("UTF8", request_result);

Comment: Can you please edit my code as per your suggestion bcoz i am not aware of this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sachin, I am not able to edit your code due to certain permisions. you just need to add the 
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'UTF8'");
$sql_fn = "your select query"
request_result = "execute associate function for get data"
mysql_set_charset("UTF8", request_result);

Comment: ok i will add it in my code. I will my update code please correct me when i will get wrong

Comment: Neeraj I have edited my code where i have add the charset after connecting to my databse.is that what u suggested

Comment: **Security risk:** Don't use `SET NAMES`

Comment: @ Neeraj Sharma Thanks... it working properly as i edited the code above.

Comment: You welcome Sachin, if it works for you then please accept the solution.

Comment: yes I was suggesting the same thing. I hope it work for you :).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what your DB encoding is, but I assume it's ISO-8859-1, because you also output your page in this encoding.

The problem is, that JSON is, by definition, *always* UTF-8 encoded. Also, PHP's `json_encode` doesn't accept input in other encodings than UTF-8; if it encounters characters in a different encoding anywhere in your object strucure, the respecive node will be `null`.

The following example will demonstrate this effect:

```
$test = array('foo' => 'äöü', 'bar' => 'äöü');
$test['foo'] = mb_convert_encoding($test['foo'], 'ISO-8859-1', 'UTF-8');
echo json_encode($test);
```

Result:

```
{"foo":null,"bar":"\u00e4\u00f6\u00fc"}
```

Solution: Convert your DB output to UTF-8, save your HTML files in UTF-8, and set your Headers to UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

Your data has to be encoded as UTF-8 or ISO-8859-1.

http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.json-encode.php

Because if you try to convert an array of non-utf8 characters you'll be getting 0 as return value